# How could I reduce the 'vertical space' between the two highlighted statements?

Tags: spacing, align

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\vspace{-1em}
\begin{flalign*}
\times a^{m}\times a^{n-m}&=\times a^{n};\,\text{(By case already proved)}&\\
\times a^{m}\times a^{n-m}\div a^{n-m}&=\times a^{n}\div a^{n-m};\,\text{(Axiom)}&\\
\times a^{m}&=\times a^{n}\div a^{n-m};\,\text{(Definition of division)}&\\
\times a^{m}\div a^{n}&=\times a^{n}\div a^{n-m}\div a^{n};\,\text{(Axiom)}&\\
\times a^{m}\div a^{n}&=\times a^{n}\div a^{n}\div a^{n-m};
\intertext{(The law of commutation for multiplication and division)}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does this notation with a leading `\times` mean?

Comment: @PeterGrill Here, the mathematical sign '\times', which exhibits the symbol of multiplication, merely indicates what has to be done with the algebraical quantity (or letter) when it enters into operation.   For example, '\times' a here indicates that it enters into operation as multiplication.  In elementary exposition, it is being asked to mention the proper operation for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it part of the equation set and use a negative vertical skip `<len>` in `\\[<len>]`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  \times a^{m}\times a^{n-m}             &= \times a^{n};                       && \text{(By case already proved)} \\
  \times a^{m}\times a^{n-m}\div a^{n-m} &= \times a^{n}\div a^{n-m};           && \text{(Axiom)} \\
  \times a^{m}                           &= \times a^{n}\div a^{n-m};           && \text{(Definition of division)} \\
  \times a^{m}\div a^{n}                 &= \times a^{n}\div a^{n-m}\div a^{n}; && \text{(Axiom)} \\
  \times a^{m}\div a^{n}                 &= \times a^{n}\div a^{n}\div a^{n-m}; \\[-\belowdisplayskip]
  \intertext{(The law of commutation for multiplication and division)}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Above the last comment in the equation is moved upward by `-\belowdisplayskip`. You can adjust this to suit your needs.

Comment: I had not known about the \belowdisplayskip environment until you brought it up.   Now, I can adjust my text with a great degree of freedom. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Since you load `mathtools` you can simply use `\shortintertext` instead of `\intertext`. I added a suggestion to improve the layout of your equation (at least for my taste), defining a `commenteq` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\newcommand\commenteq[1]{\text{\footnotesize(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\vspace{-1em}
\begin{flalign*}
   × a^{m} × a^{n-m}&= × aⁿ;\,\text{(By case already proved)}&\\
   × a^{m} × a^{n-m}\div a^{n-m}&= × aⁿ\div a^{n-m};\,\text{(Axiom)}&\\
   × a^{m}&= × aⁿ\div a^{n-m};\,\text{(Definition of division)}&\\
   × a^{m}\div aⁿ&= × aⁿ\div a^{n-m}\div aⁿ;\,\text{(Axiom)}&\\
   × a^{m}\div aⁿ&= × aⁿ\div aⁿ\div a^{n-m};
  \shortintertext{(The law of commutation for multiplication and division)}
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
  {} × a^{m} × a^{n-m}&= × aⁿ; && \commenteq{By case already proved}\\
  {} × a^{m} × a^{n-m}\div a^{n-m}&= × aⁿ\div a^{n-m}; && \commenteq{Axiom}\\
  {} × a^{m}&= × aⁿ\div a^{n-m}; & &\commenteq{Definition of division}\\
  {} × a^{m}\div aⁿ&= × aⁿ\div a^{n-m}\div aⁿ; && \commenteq{Axiom}\\
  {} × a^{m}\div aⁿ&= × aⁿ\div aⁿ\div a^{n-m};
  \shortintertext{(The law of commutation for multiplication and division)}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made the aforementioned improvement for my next set of equations and the layout came off quite nicely.   Thank you for the suggestion, Bernard!  '\commenteq' command is much easier to use.